# How To Keep Fields Locked Until Edit Button Is Pressed On VB

Tags: vb.net

I'm Virtually a New Coder Using VB For My School Project. On One Of My Forms I Have Many Fields Which Can Be Edited, I Have An Edit Button And a Save Button. I Was The Fields To Be Inaccessible Until The 'Edit' Button Is Clicked Which Then Lets The User Again Fill In Those Fields

Comment: Put Them On A Panel And Toggle the Enabled Property

Comment: Please read this advice on asking good questions: [[ask]], [[Writing the perfect question](http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints)]. Pay special attention to the "Golden Rule", though I highly advise you to read the entire article.

Comment: Are you using Windows Forms or Web Forms?

Comment: I'm Using Windows Forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the enabled property of each field to false
Then under btn_click event set txtBox.Enabled = true